# Autoconf: linker error linking against custom library

Tags: c, cross-compiling, autoconf, automake

1) I have a project containing a shared library that links against some foreign libraries (namely `gcrypt`, `gpg-error`, `z` and `ssh2`). Lets call it "mylib".
This library builds perfectly and I can see `libtool` linking the dependencies correctly.

```
libtool: link: ppc-linux-gcc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/mylib1.o .libs/mylib2.o .libs/mylib3.o
     -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/ELDK/ppc_8xx/lib -Wl,-rpath \
     -Wl,/opt/ELDK/ppc_8xx/lib /opt/ELDK/ppc_8xx/lib/libssh2.so \
     -L/opt/ELDK/ppc_8xx/lib -lz /opt/ELDK/ppc_8xx/lib/libgcrypt.so \
     /opt/ELDK/ppc_8xx/lib/libgpg-error.so -lpthread  -O2 \
     -Wl,-soname -Wl,mylib.so.0 -o .libs/mylib.so.0.0.0
```

2) The same project has several programs that link to "mylib".
When I try to link them, though, I got linker errors about the same previous libraries:

```
/opt/ELDK-3.1/usr/bin/../lib/gcc-lib/ppc-linux/3.3.3/../../../../ppc-linux/bin/ld: \
     warning: libssh2.so.1, needed by ./../myLib/.libs/mylib.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/opt/ELDK-3.1/usr/bin/../lib/gcc-lib/ppc-linux/3.3.3/../../../../ppc-linux/bin/ld: \
     warning: libz.so.1, needed by ./../myLib/.libs/mylib.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/opt/ELDK-3.1/usr/bin/../lib/gcc-lib/ppc-linux/3.3.3/../../../../ppc-linux/bin/ld: \
     warning: libgcrypt.so.11, needed by ./../myLib/.libs/mylib.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/opt/ELDK-3.1/usr/bin/../lib/gcc-lib/ppc-linux/3.3.3/../../../../ppc-linux/bin/ld: \
     warning: libgpg-error.so.0, needed by ./../myLib/.libs/mylib.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
./../myLib/.libs/mylib.so: undefined reference to `libssh2_channel_process_startup'
./../myLib/.libs/mylib.so: undefined reference to `libssh2_scp_send_ex'
```

In the "mylib" `configure.ac` I explicitly search for the libraries:

```
AC_SEARCH_LIBS(gpg_err_set_errno,[gpg-error])
AC_SEARCH_LIBS(gcry_check_version,[gcrypt])
AC_SEARCH_LIBS(deflate,[z])
AC_SEARCH_LIBS(libssh2_init,[ssh2])
```

Must I also explicitly include all of those libraries in every project using "mylib"?
Shouldn't it be already resolved when I first link them in "mylib"?

Is there any better way to do this?

Thanks.

P.S.: I am not very clever in `autoconf` matter, sorry.

NOTE: I am cross compiling for PowerPC using (the yet old) ELDK 3.1.

Comment: Do you override any of the directives for your program in Makefile.am?

Comment: I have something like `program1_CPPFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir) $(MYLIB_CFLAGS)` where `MYLIB_CFLAGS` and `MYLIB_LIBS` are defined with `AC_ARG_WITH` in `configure.ac` of "program1" to allow me to link to a local "mylib" instead of a system installed one (please tell me if it is a better way of doing this).

Comment: CPPFLAGS should not be relevant, but how do you use MYLIB_LIBS in Makefile.am?  In your final Makefile, there should be a target for program1$(EXEEXT) that contains a $(LINK) command, and that command should have $(LIBS), which should contain the libraries if AC_SEARCH_LIBS was successful in finding the given library.

Comment: The output of running ldd on mylib.so would be useful, although I'm not sure how easy that is to do when you're cross-compiling.  Also interesting would be to check with `readelf -a` to ensure that the RPATH was actually added like you requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:** Since I have received an answer 2 years latter and that was not what solved my problem, I think it is better to share with everyone what I have done.

---

***ANSWER:***

The better way I found out to automatically include linker dependencies in a `autoconf` based project was to add `pkg-config` information to my library.

*Changes to `configure.ac`:*

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=../MyLibPath:${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([DEPS], [libssh2 >= 1.3.0])

# Output configuration files.
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile libMyLib-1.0.pc libMyLib-1.0-uninstalled.pc])
```

The second output file `libMyLib-1.0-uninstalled.pc` is to allow me to continue developing my project with an uninstalled version of MyLib.

*Changes to `Makefile.am`:*

```
libMyLib_la_CPPFLAGS  = $(DEPS_CPPFLAGS)
libMyLib_la_CFLAGS    = $(DEPS_CFLAGS)
libMyLib_la_CXXFLAGS  = $(DEPS_CXXFLAGS)
libMyLib_la_LIBADD    = $(DEPS_LIBS)

pkgconfigdir = $(libdir)/pkgconfig
pkgconfig_DATA = libMyLib-1.0.pc
```

*Add to project `libMyLib-1.0.pc`:*

```
prefix=@prefix@
exec_prefix=@exec_prefix@
libdir=@libdir@
includedir=@includedir@

Name: MyLib
Description: My library.
Requires: libssh2
Requires.private:
Version: @PACKAGE_VERSION@
Libs: -L${libdir} -lMyLib -lstdc++ -lm -lslog -lpthread
Libs.private:
Cflags: -I${includedir}/libMyLib-1.0
```

*and `libMyLib-1.0-uninstalled.pc`:*

```
prefix=@abs_builddir@
exec_prefix=@exec_prefix@
libdir=${prefix}/.libs
includedir=${prefix}

Name: MyLib
Description: My library.
Requires: libssh2
Requires.private:
Version: @PACKAGE_VERSION@
Libs: -Wl,-rpath-link,${libdir} -L${libdir} -lMyLib -lstdc++ -lm -lslog -lpthread
Libs.private:
Cflags: -I${includedir}/
```

**In each dependent project:**

`configure.ac`:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=../MyLibPath:${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([MYLIB], [libMyLib-1.0 >= 1.0.0])
```

`Makefile.am`:

```
dependent_CPPFLAGS  = $(MYLIB_CPPFLAGS)
dependent_CFLAGS    = $(MYLIB_CFLAGS)
dependent_CXXFLAGS  = $(MYLIB_CXXFLAGS)
dependent_LIBADD    = $(MYLIB_LIBS)
```

Comment: You shouldn't need `-rpath-link` in the Libs entry unless `libslog` or the standard libraries are in different paths as well.

Comment: Yes, it is in a different path in the `uninstalled` profile. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's harder to tell exactly what you're doing without knowing what's in your `Makefile.am` or `configure.ac`, but since I see you're using `-Wl,-rpath`, I assume that you're passing it as `LDFLAGS` from the outside when you call `./configure`.

What happens is that `libtool` will not usually store the `-rpath` values but it'll store `-L`; so my usual suggestion is to pass both `-L` and `-rpath` so that the `.la` files will contain the path where to find the libraries to link to it.

While you don't have to pass it on every single binary, `libtool` will, and will then let the link editor resolve it properly.

Comment: Really thanks for answering Diego. I ended up by putting `pkgconfig` to play and it solved my problem. Now I don't have to repeat the linked libraries for each dependency. It is disappointing, though, that `autoconf` is not able to automatically "cascade" this dependencies...

Comment: You can only cascade shared object dependencies, but not static archives, but in this case it seems to me like you have some extra dependency that is in a different path altogether, and that is trickier because its search paths change.

Comment: The annoying think is that I had to keep repeating the dependent (shared) libraries in the shared projects. Despite `MyLib` was already dynamically linked, the final program/library was giving linker errors if I omit the (already linked in MyLib) dependencies.

Comment: Are those part of the system libraries or in a separate path? It seems like the link editor does not know where to look for them.